# PHP curl Inside Foreach

Tags: php, curl, foreach

EDIT:What is really happening is that a new xml is created each time but it is adding the new $html information to the previous so by the time it gets to the last element in the list being curled, it is saving parsed information from all previous curls. Can't figure out what is wrong.

Having trouble with a curl not executing as expected. In the code below I have a foreach loop that loops thru a list ($textarray) and passes the list element to a curl and also used to create an xml file using the element as the file name. The curl then returns $html which is then parsed and saved to an xml. The script runs, the list is passed, the url is created and passed to the curl function. I get an echo showing the correct url, a return is made and then each return is parsed and saved to the appropriate file.  The problem seems to be that the curl is not actually curling the new $url. I get the exact same information saved in every xml file. I no this is not correct. Not sure why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

```
     Function FeedXml($textarray){
     $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
     $feed=$doc->createElement("feed");
     Foreach ($textarray as $text){
     $url="http://xxx/xxx/".$text;
     echo "PATH TO CURL".$url."<br>";
     $html=curlurl($url);  
     $xmlsave="http://xxxx/xxx/".$text;
     $dom = new DOMDocument(); //NEW dom FOR EACH SHOW
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $dom->loadHTML($html);
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $dom->formatOutput = true;
     $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
 //PARSE EACH RETURN INFORMATION
     $images= $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
     foreach($images as $img){
     $icon= $img    ->getAttribute('src');
     if( preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)(?:[\?\#].*)?$/i', $icon) ) { 
 // ITEM TAG
     $item= $doc->createElement("item");
     $sdAttribute = $doc->createAttribute("sdImage");
     $sdAttribute->value = $icon;  
     $item->appendChild($sdAttribute); 
     } //  IMAGAGE FOR EACH
     $feed->appendChild($item);
     $doc->appendChild($feed);      
     $doc->save($xmlsave);
     }
     }
     }

     Function curlurl($url){
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//0-FALSE  1 TRUE
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,'10');
     $html = curl_exec($ch);
     $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch);
     echo $httpcode;
     return $html;
     }
```

Comment: WTH is with the -1 and no comments?

Comment: I you are going to down vote, at least give explanation. Of course the question is not something of great importance to everybody but it does hold some validity in that it might point out a mistake others may make.

Comment: For starters, you should properly indent your code, so that it is actually readable.

Comment: What is not indented correctly?

Comment: Everything actually.

Comment: Well – _everything_ …?

Comment: Besides, the code is invalid, there's one `{` more than `}`. And there's this: `$url"<br>"`.

Comment: Well, when posted the site didn't kick it out as being indented incorrectly.  The code was indented at least 4 spaces. As far as the extra { , must have overlooked putting in the one to close the function. Thank you for pointing that out, and the indent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out my shortcomings on the above. I have figured out the problem.  The following needed to be moved into the Foreach.

```
     $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
     $feed=$doc->createElement("feed");
```